# Lookup field Update in Salesforce

Tags: trigger

I want an example of a trigger for example:
I want to update a field which is a field on the lookup object's field due to changes made on the current object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to copy Contact StreetName to Account StreetName (Account is the lookup field on Contact.  This should work.

```
if(trigger.isAfter){                
        if(trigger.isUpdate){            
            for(Contact c: trigger.new){
                    List<Account> AccList = [SELECT Id,StreetName FROM Account WHERE Id=: c.AccountId LIMIT 1];
                    if(AccList.size()>0){
                           AccList[0].StreetName = c.StreetName;
                           update AccList[0];
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: this is a bad answer. A query inside the loop is not the best practice. For more info take a look at this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops

Comment: @Novarg Any idea about my answer ?

Comment: Somehow this is correct !!! for less records

Comment: It's not bulkified and will fail on mass updates. SOQL and DMLs should always be out of loops.